# Cannot get correct syntax for @Html.ListBoxFor()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.listboxfor

I've a series of @Html components which are built dynamically including ListBoxFor(). With the others I've given them an ID which I then use to populate a  model value called inputvalues, which holds the values of each component whenever it changes. This works well but I had to change the original DropDownListFor() for ListBoxFor() but although the new syntax works, I cannot assign it an ID value as I did before without getting a syntax error. The code looks like this..

```
@if (Model != null)
{  
    @Styles.Render(BundleConfig.Styles_MultiSelect)

    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> filetypes = from filetype in Model.ListOptions
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Value = filetype.ID.ToString(),
        Text = filetype.Name,
        Selected = Model.SelectedListOptionID == null ? false : Model.SelectedListOptionID > 0
    };

    <div class="editor-section">
        <div class="label">
            @Html.DisplayEditLabel(Model.Label, Model.Required.Value)
        </div>
        <div class="field large-text-field">
            @*Original drop down replaced by ListBoxFor() but with ID
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedListOptionID, new SelectList(Model.ListOptions, "ID", "Name", Model.SelectedListOptionID).OrderBy(l => l.Value), new Dictionary<string, object>{
                 {"id", "personField_" + Model.ID}})*@

            @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.ListOptions, filetypes, new { @class = "multiselectFileTypes" })
        </div>
    </div>
}    
@Scripts.Render(BundleConfig.Scripts_MultiSelect)
<script>
    $("#personField_" + "@Model.ID").change(function () {
        cnt++;

        var uploadValue = JSON.stringify({
            "id": "@Model.ID",
            "order": cnt,
            "required": "@Model.Required",
            "libraryUploadConfigType": 3,
            "customFieldTypeID": 5,
            "selectedListOptionID": $(this).val()
        });

        inputValues = inputValues + uploadValue;
    });


    $(".multiselectFileTypes").multiselect({
        noneSelectedText: 'All Options',
        minWidth: 230,
        selectedList: 6
    });
</script>
```

Although the syntax for the original DropDownlistFor() worked and updated inputvalues the component didn't work. Having changed it to ListBoxFor() the component works but I can't seem to assign the ID 'personField_' without getting an error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think you need to change the default `id` attribute that is created by the method?

Comment: As it is right now with DropDownListFor() commented out and ListBoxFor()  with no ID, the script never runs when an item is selected. Although it did with DropDownListFor() the choice of component was wrong. How do I assign the same ID to ListBoxFor(0 so that the script will run?

Comment: Your `ListBoxFor()` method is generating `<select id="ListOptions" ... >` so just use `$("#ListOptions").change(function () {`

Comment: That worked, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See reply from Stephen Meucke above.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see that you try to assign ID in your `ListBoxFor` helper.

It should be like this:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedListOptionIDs, filetypes, new { @class = "multiselectFileTypes" })
```

And `SelectedListOptionIDs` field of your model should be `IList` or `IEnumerable`, or `Array` of your ID type (probably `IList<int>`). Then it will work fine on View and bind correct on form **POST**.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, it works fine as it is with filetypes as my IEnumerable class list but how can I give the ListBoxFor() an ID like I did with the original DropDownListFor()?

Comment: @user616076 i gess there are to simple way to do it. It's better to init your IEnumerable with single value then it will work fine